# remove an element if it exists for all sub-elements of a list

Tags: r

I come across lists that I would like to parse before coercing into a data frame. Sometimes I have lists that have elements I'm not expecting.  I'd like to be able to remove all of these unexpected elements by name when they arise.  Here is an example of a list with an element `wackything` that I would like removed without having to call the element index or using a for loop through each sub-element.

```
my_list <- list(person = list(name = "mike", phone = "111-1111"), 
 person = list(name = "lisa", phone = "222-2222", wackything = "PLEASE REMOVE ME"),
 person = list(name = "kimo", phone = "333-3333"))
```

I would like my final list to look like this:

```
final_list <- list(person = list(name = "mike", phone = "111-1111"), 
            person = list(name = "lisa", phone = "222-2222"),
            person = list(name = "kimo", phone = "333-3333"))
```

so that I can corece it to a data frame using

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(final_list, rbind))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you have too many rbinds in your anticipated use. See if this is satisfactory:

```
> rmwac <- function(x) x[ !names(x) %in% "wackything"]
> do.call(rbind, lapply(my_list, rmwac))
       name   phone     
person "mike" "111-1111"
person "lisa" "222-2222"
person "kimo" "333-3333"
```

Notice that epi10's perfectly fine answer use a negative sign and that was possible because `grep` returns numeric values and indexing of lists with numeric values is possible. It is not, however, possible to use the negative sign with character and logical values.

Comment: Thanks! R doesn't like the duplicate row names when converting it to a data.frame.

Comment: Use: `as.data.frame( do.call(rbind, lapply(my_list, rmwac)), row.names=-1 )`

Answer (score 5):

`bind_rows` from the `dplyr` package will work even if not all the lists share the same element names. Then you can remove the columns you don't need.

```
library(dplyr)

df = bind_rows(my_list)
```

> ```
>    name    phone       wackything
> 1  mike 111-1111               NA
> 2  lisa 222-2222 PLEASE REMOVE ME
> 3  kimo 333-3333               NA
> ```

```
df = df[ , -grep("wackything", names(df))]
```

> ```
>    name    phone
> 1  mike 111-1111
> 2  lisa 222-2222
> 3  kimo 333-3333
> ```

Answer (score 2):

You could try this. The first step is similar to 42-'s answer. We then use `sapply`, which returns a matrix that we then have to transpose.

```
my_list <- lapply(my_list, function(x)x[names(x)!= "wackything"])
data.frame(t(sapply(my_list,c)), row.names=NULL)

#  name    phone
#1 mike 111-1111
#2 lisa 222-2222
#3 kimo 333-3333
```

Another option that gives you the same result.

```
data.frame(Reduce(rbind, my_list), row.names=NULL)
```

We use `row.names=NULL` when building the dataframe. You can do it without but that will result in a warning message related to the duplicate rownames that we have.